# Msg 8114: Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am writing a dynamic query in SSMS 2008 and I get the above error.  What is the cause of this?

My query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM 
    ALL_COMPLAINTS A
JOIN 
    #TEMP5 B ON A.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO = B.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO 
                AND A.[LEVEL] = B.[LEVEL] 
                AND A.[QXP_REPORT_DATE] = B.[QXP_REPORT_DATE]
WHERE 
    A.QXP_REPORT_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '' + @FirstMonthDate + ' 00:00:00', 102) 
    AND 
    A.QXP_REPORT_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '' + @LastMonthDate + ' 23:59:59', 102) 
    AND 
    A.QXP_SHORT_DESC <> 'Design Control' AND A.LEVEL = ' + CAST(@TheLevel AS VARCHAR(5)) + '
```

I know that `A.Level` is numeric and I also know that I do not get any errors if I just remove the `A.Level` portion. However, I am not certain I am casting `@TheLevel` correctly since this is dynamic SQL.

Comment: If `A.LEVEL` is numeric, how can it be equal to the string ` + CAST(@TheLevel AS VARCHAR(5) + `? Did you miss something in your query?

Comment: This doesn't look like dynamic SQL despite your last sentence! In dynamic SQL you construct the whole string then execute it. It looks like you are just chucking random strings containing TSQL fragments into your query and expecting it to work?

Comment: I also tried CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) but I got the same error message.

Comment: @Martin, I don't follow u.  How is this incomplete?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed this now.  Here is the new code:

Comment: A.LEVEL = CAST(@TheLevel AS NUMERIC(10,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are messed up in the last line, you cant mix dynamic and non dynamic SQL in the same statement. Also assuming @TheLevel is a numeric, if @TheLevel is a char, you need to convert it to a numeric (int I assume in this case)

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM 
    ALL_COMPLAINTS A
JOIN 
    #TEMP5 B ON A.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO = B.QXP_EXCEPTION_NO 
                AND A.[LEVEL] = B.[LEVEL] 
                AND A.[QXP_REPORT_DATE] = B.[QXP_REPORT_DATE]
WHERE 
    A.QXP_REPORT_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '' + @FirstMonthDate + ' 00:00:00', 102) 
    AND 
    A.QXP_REPORT_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '' + @LastMonthDate + ' 23:59:59', 102) 
    AND 
    A.QXP_SHORT_DESC <> 'Design Control' AND A.LEVEL = @TheLevel
```

If you need a dynamic portion then it is probably good practice to pre evaluate it and then key it into the non dynamic query